# AWS AppSync Graphql equivalent of a left join query

Tags: left-join, aws-appsync

I am trying to join two dynamoDb tables to get a result set similar to a left join. Here is a scaled down version of the tables in question

```
  type MaintenanceRecomendationsMaster
  @model
  @key(name: "byrecomendID", fields: ["recomendId"], queryField: "byrecomendID") {
  id: ID!
  recomendId: Int!
  displayName: String!
  history: [UserMaintenanceHistory]
    @connection(keyName: "byRecomendationsMasterId", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Here is the other table it joins to

```
type UserMaintenanceHistory
@model
  @key(name: "byUserVehicleId", fields: ["uservehicleId"])
  @key(name: "byRecomendationsMasterId", fields: ["RecomendationsMasterId"]) {
  id: ID!
  status: String
  actionTakenDate: AWSDateTime
  uservehicleId: ID!
  RecomendationsMasterId: ID!
  maintenanceCache: MaintenanceRecomendationsMaster
    @connection(fields: ["RecomendationsMasterId"])
}
```

This is what the tables looks like with the data
[image]

I want to be able to send in recommendId =100 and uservehicleId = 1 to get a response like this
[image]

The query I am using like this works but it uses the filter clause which uses a scan operation and has a limitation of only fetching the first 100 records and then applying the filter on those 100 records. I want to run a query where I am currently running a filter right now if possible.  I don't want to use custom resolvers if possible, unless that is the only way out.

```
    query byrecomendIdQuery{
        byrecomendId(recomendId: 100) {
        items {
            id
            displayName
            history (filter: {uservehicleId: {eq: "1"}})  {
            items{
                status
                actionTakenDate
             }
            }
         }
        }
    }
```